# How to get price from mysql using laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5

I am trying to get the adult and child price form a table where id is 3. How can I do this using Laravel?

```
------------------
id adult child
------------------
2   100  50
3   200  100
```

I am not sure how to continue after this
`$price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)`

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first() returns the first record ,looks like you need single model to return

```
$price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->first();
```

If you have multiple model

```
$price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->get();
```

If you just need price , use pluck

```
$price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->pluck('price');
```

EDIT
Looks like you edit your question , so I need to edit my answer

```
$price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->select('adult', 'child')->first();
```

Comment: thank you very much so I have to do 2 plucks. for adult `DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->pluck('adult')` and for child `DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->pluck('child')` Am I right?

Comment: I got an error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.. when I used `->select('id', 'adult')->first();` I think you meant `adult` instead `name` but it worked when I used `$price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->pluck('adult');`

Comment: $price = DB::table('tours')->where('id', 3)->select('adult', 'child')->first();

Comment: I get an error Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int
 when I do this `echo 2 * $price` do you know the reason?